# JSON formatting navigation python

Tags: python, shopify

I am trying to retrieve the titles of multiple items that have been under a single order.
There can be multiple subsections under the 'line_items' where the information of each item is displayed, title being one of the parameters for every item.

[0] brings me the first item title.

[-1] brings me the last item title.

How do I interact with the subsections in between? Is there a way to return all associated order titles whether there's 1 or more?

```
  r = requests.get("jsonURL", params="jsonparams")
  data = r.json()

  for item in data['orders']:
    purchased = item['line_items'][0]['title']
    purchased1 = item['line_items'][-1]['title']
```

Comment: You need a loop and some data structure to store the results (probably a list). The explanation of both is way beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: If you can provide an example of what the data looks like, I  can try to write something up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding an inner loop like this:

```
r = requests.get("jsonURL", params="jsonparams")
data = r.json()

for items in data['orders']:
    for item in items['line_items']:
       print(item['title'])
```

This will print out the titles of the items in each of the orders.

If you only want to print out a subset of the items you can use a slice on the `items['line_items']`. If you want to print only the first `n` items, then you would write `items['line_items'][:n]`. If you want to print only the last `n` items, you would write `items['line_items'][-n]`. You can even combine the two, for instance `items['line_items'][1:-2]` will skip the first and last two items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps for you.

```
r = requests.get("jsonURL", params="jsonparams")
data = r.json()

result = [items['items'] for items in data['orders']['line_items']]
```

If you want to get the first index:

```
print(result[0])
```

If you want to get the first index:

```
print(result[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON from your code will look somewhat like this:

```
    data =  {
        "orders": {
        "line_items": [
            {
                "title": "abc"
            },
            {
                "title": "def"
            },
            {
                "title": "ghi"
            },
            {
                "title": "jkl"
            },
            {
                "title": "mno"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, in order to get titles for all items, loop through each item in the `line_items` list, look for the 'title' key and append its values to an empty list called `purchased`:

```
purchased = []
for item in data['orders']['line_items']:
    if 'title' in item.keys():
        purchased.append(item['title'])
print(purchased)
#Output:
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']
```

If you also want the quantity of each item purchased, you can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(purchased))
#Output:
Counter({'abc': 1, 'def': 1, 'ghi': 1, 'jkl': 1, 'mno': 1})
```